# When memory is allocated for non staic final variables?

Tags: java

We know that memory is allocated for static variables at the time of class loading. Is it true for final non-static variables as well. I know that a new copy of final variable will be exist in every instances of the class.I think that, first copy of the final non-static variable will be created at the time of class loading itself. please explain

Comment: " I know that a new copy of final variable will be exist in every instances of the class" - yes. "I think that, first copy of the final non-static variable will be created at the time of class loading itself" - why? What instance would that be associated with? When would it be used?

Comment: As its value never changes after initialization,I think we can associate it with the class itself .Every new instance can refer or take the same copy of it while instantiating the class.Take the case of final non-static var which is also initialized at the time of declaration like 'final int x = 4;'. Here we cant change its value even through a constructor. It will be same for each object. so I think it will be better if memory allocation for such var happens at class loading time itself like its done for static vars.

Comment: Just because it doesn't change after initialization doesn't mean it's constant. For example: `private final long creationTime = System.currentTimeMillis()`. Why would it make any sense to have a copy of that variable anywhere other than an instance? And if you're going to copy the value into an instance anyway, where are you saving memory? (Each object is the same size - it's just that you've got an *additional* object, effectively.) Writing a constant value into a field isn't exactly a slow operation...

Answer (score 3):

It is true that memory for static fields is allocated at class loading. Or rather, at the class linking stage, which is separate from the loading.

But this has nothing to do with final non-static fields.

First, you simply can't "allocate" memory for a field without allocating memory for the entire object it belongs to. The field is going to be part of an object. And the object is only going to be allocated space once you use the `new` operator for it.

But perhaps you thought that its value is going to be prepared in advance during class loading, and then copied over to the new instances as soon as they are created?

Consider the following case:

```
class A {
    private final int myInt;

    public A( int valueForMyInt ) {

        myInt = valueForMyInt;

    }

    // Other constructors and methods
}
```

The value of `myInt` here is set during *contruction* time. The fact that a field is final doesn't mean that all its copies in all the instances are the same. You can initialize a final field either with a constant initializer, an initializing block or in the constructor, and the value they set in it doesn't have to be the same for each instance. You can create new instances with `new A(15)`, `new A(27)` or whatever integer you want.

Therefore, there is no reason that a final field should be set up earlier than the rest of the instance. It is allocated exactly the same way as non-final fields. The only difference is that it can't be assigned a second time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply,I agree with all your lines but take the case of final non-static var which is also initialized at the time of declaration like 'final int myInt = 4;'. Here we cant change its value even through the constructor. It will be same for each object. so I think it will be better if memory allocation for such var happens at class loading time itself.Even if we are initalizing it with constructor,the memory allocation for the final non-static var with its default value can be done at class loading time itself.

Comment: @Linda, no it can't. As I said, you allocate memory for the entire object at the same time. And `int` is a primitive type - it is just four bytes of memory which are part of the object. If you allocate it in advance, how are you going to connect it to the actual object when you create it?

Comment: *It is true that memory for static fields is allocated at class loading.* - shouldn't it be during *class initialization*?. @Linda - `final int x=4` will become a *compile time constant*.

Comment: @TheLostMind Right. Corrected statement.

Comment: @RealSkeptic - No. *loading*, *linking* and *initialization* are different phases. You usually have a *Linker-Loader* as one module.

Comment: @TheLostMind: [JLS Chapter 12](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.3): Linking consists of *verification*, *preparation*, and *resolution*. Further ahead, the *preparation* stage involves creating with default values. That's what I'm referring to as "memory allocation". Assigning values, I agree, is separate.

Answer (score 0):

Non-static fields are created at object's creation time. Consider this example.

```
class MyClass {
    public static int staticVar = 1;

    public final int finalVar = staticVar;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyClass m1 = new MyClass();
        MyClass.staticVar = 2;
        MyClass m2 = new MyClass();
        System.out.println(m1.finalVar);
        System.out.println(m2.finalVar);
    }
}
```

This outputs:

> 1
>   2